# Is there a way to define aliases and use it CSS definitions in Sass or Less

Tags: css, sass, less

**EDIT: Achieve this approach without using `@mixin` and `@include`**

Currently I'm using Sass as my CSS precompiler for a large and brand new project. I admit it, I really liked the idea behind this tools and it becomes more usable when you want to use it with `@mixin` functions.

I want to use Sass more quickly. My thought is, assign aliases to variables and just use it in CSS declaration. Consider the following code blocks.

```
$backgroundColor: #F1F2F2;

body {
    background: $backgroundColor;
}
```

works fine in Sass. But I want to achieve,

```
$backgroundColor: "background: #F1F2F2";

body {
    $backgroundColor;
}
```

This block returns error in Sass. Any idea, or is it possible to use Sass in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@mixin backgroundColor {
    background: #F1F2F2;
}

body {
    @include backgroundColor;
}
```

Should work.

Comment: Well, I knew this should work, in fact I want to throw away "@mixin" and "@include".

Comment: @Fatih, why? `@include` and `@extend` are the Sass patterns for doing what you want.

Comment: I've said my purpose in my question "I want to use Sass more quickly."

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it gets quicker than that with the SCSS syntax.

Comment: @Fatih, you might save a few keystrokes, but it's not idiomatic and I can't imagine that it would save time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with SASS (it's great, though) and I don't have any idea whether you can assign a property name as the value of a variable but what might be wrong in your way of shortening may be a data type issue. Since property names and values do not seem to be single/double quoted strings (and since you use quotes) this situation might confuse SASS. I think you should give the below pattern a try:

```
$backgroundColor: background + : + #F1F2F2;

body {
    $backgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work: [Sass Error: Invalid CSS after "...: background + ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ": + #F1F2F2;"](http://sass-lang.com/try.html)